# Class Methods in C#

Tags: c#

In Ruby, we can create a class method by doing:

```
 def self.class_method
   "This is a class method"
 end

 def instance_method
   "This is an instance method"
 end
```

How can I create a class method in C#?

Comment: Why don't you take 5 seconds to Google a simple C# tutorial?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

....`static` and non-`static`..

```
public class YourObject {
    public static void MyClassMethod() { // "class method" is a static method
    }

    public void MyInstanceMethod() {
    }
}

// callable as..

YourObject.MyClassMethod();
// or..
YourObject obj = new YourObject();
obj.MyInstanceMethod(); // OK
```

Any tutorial covers this..

Answer (score -1):

```
public class YourClass
{
   public string Foo()
   {
      return "Hello World"
   }

}

YourClass yourClass = new YourClass();
Console.Write(yourClass.Foo());
```

Comment: That code wouldn't even compile, it's missing a semicolon. Also, it doesn't answer the question at all.